# Bar code library for Android

Tags: android

Is there any Barcode library available for Android, which i can make of use for Scanning the products?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The canonical library is Zebra Crossing: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

All ready for Android, too.

Enjoy.

Comment: Definitely THE standard library.

Comment: I can't find anywhere, does it support bar- and qr-codes generation?

Comment: documentation sux. also it's NOT a library, its an open source app.